# Using if to compare column values

Tags: r, function

Here's my df, labeled "Task".

|  | Country | Confirmed | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Austria | 2510071 | 28.2 |
| 2 | Bolivia | 888175 | 7.8 |

I am required to use an if-else statement to do two things: (1) determine which value in the "Ratio" column is greater, and (2) create a new column that says either "Highest" or "Lowest" for the appropriate observation.

I've read dozens of posts about using if-else, but I cannot seem to find examples of a condition that says "see if the 'Ratio' value in this row is greater or lesser than the 'Ratio' value in another row". I've made lots of if() attempts, but they've all failed pretty miserably.

My goal is code that'll produce this output:

|  | Country | Confirmed | Ratio | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Austria | 2510071 | 28.2 | Highest |
| 2 | Bolivia | 888175 | 7.8 | Lowest |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data frame only has two observations (i.e., rows), what you want is fairly straightforward:

```
# Create some sample data...
df <- data.frame(
  Country = c("Austria", "Boliva"),
  Ratio = c(28.2, 7.8)
)  

# Create a new variable in the data frame...
df$Rank <- ifelse(df$Ratio == max(df$Ratio), "Highest", "Lowest")
```

Comment: 'm grateful, rdelrossi! That worked perfectly. May I ask you a followup question? Why was it necessary to perform 'df <- tibble::tribble()' first, since I already had the data frame created? Thanks again

Comment: It's not necessary for you to create the data frame. I did that here to create some sample data in order to show a full solution. That's a preferred way to post a question here so that it's easier to have data to work with. If your data frame is named `Task` then you would write `Task$Rank <- ifelse(Task$Ratio == max(Task$Ratio), "Highest", "Lowest")`.